# ASP.Net Core Identity with JwtBearer AuthenticationScheme map claims to context User object

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal, jwt

I have a React Front end using the msal lib to authenticate the user client side with our Azure AD. This works great and authentication has no issues. I also have an ASP.Net Core WebApi to provide data to the client. I am using the JwtTokens to pass the `Bearer token` in the request. The WebApi is able to validate the token and all is well... I thought, however, when the WebApi method is invoked the only way I can get the User's email or name is to query the User.Claims with Linq.

`this.User.Claims.Where(c=> c.Type == "preferred_username").FirstOrDefault().Value`

I was about to go down the road of mapping these linq queries to an object which could be injected into the WebApi's controller, but that seems wrong.

I am obviously missing something in my Startup.cs for the WebApi, Any help or suggestions would be great!:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            //add authentication JwtBearer Scheme
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                    {
                        options.Audience = Configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"];
                        options.Authority = Configuration["JwtSettings:Authority"];
                        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                        {
                            OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
                            {
                                //log
                                return Task.CompletedTask;
                            },
                            OnAuthenticationFailed = ctx =>
                            {
                                //log
                                return Task.CompletedTask;
                            }
                        };
                        options.SaveToken = true;
                    });

            services.AddAuthorization();

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by _I was about to go down the road of mapping these linq queries to an object which could be injected into the WebApi's controller_ , auto model binding from a User to database model?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to figure out how to bind the Jwtoken claims to IdentityUser model in Asp.Net core. In the past we have always used cookie based auth but we cannot in this app.